# Using Spring Boot Rest Template gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, java-ee-8

I am trying to execute the following syntax : -

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(Pl4WhatsAppConstants.chatBotURL + botId + "/converse/" + senderId, entity,
                    ConverseResponses.class).getBody();
```

I am getting the following error : -
Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection

I am using the following version of code : -

1. JDK :
   openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_272-b10)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.272-b10, mixed mode)
2. Spring Boot version : 2.3.4.RELEASE

How do I add the missing class definition to the war?

Comment: Did you make Restemplate calss intilisation ?

Comment: I used Spring dependency injection.